# Incorrect back-end processing in case slow connection

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a codeigniter-based web-application with MySQL base.
There is a particular form, which runs data updates on the server side.
When it is used in local network or using fast connection, everything is fine.

But sometimes I have to use an unstable cell network connection. Sometimes it works fine, but sometimes it works weird: it performs just a piece of server logic (it should update 3 tables, but it updates only the first one, UI is hanging...)

I tired transactions - it doesn't work at all.

Comment: if you are talking about one request - i dont think this has to do anything with a slow connection - because either you've a valid request or not (there is no half request or such thing...)

Comment: I'm with @sintakonte its either `true` or `false`, nothing in between.

Comment: Regardless of the type of connection, if you have 3 updates that should all happen as a single group you should enclose them in a transaction so their either all work or all fail. Your tables would need to be using the InnoDB engine to support using transactions.

Comment: If you need to update million of records on those tables, maybe the problem could be your PHP script being stoped... maybe for memory limit or something like that?

Comment: It's not a case with huge number of records. These are minor data updates.

Comment: I mentioned the slow connection not as a root cause. It's just a step to reproduce an issue. Data is 100% correct, so the problem is not in logic.